# Loading a default favicon.ico if one does not already exist on page

Tags: php, html

Is there an elegant way of loading a default favicon **only if no other favicon is currently loaded** on a particular page?

Essentially,

```
if (favicon.ico exists) { 
    //do nothing
} 
else { 
    load default favicon.ico 
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Currently loaded by who, the browser? You can't know that in PHP. Can you elaborate what you want to achieve?

Comment: favicon.ico is just a file that sits somewhere in your website hierarchy (as far as the browser is concerned).  What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: More of a hypothetical question, if I allow users to load their own for instance. I want a default to show no matter what, but if they have one specified I want that loaded. Wasn't sure if there was a great way to handle that use case. Not even sure what happens if 2 different favicons are loaded on one page, is only one of them used, or does it shoot an error.

Answer (score 1):

If no favicon is specified on the page, the browser should look for `/favicon.ico` (in other words, the file named `favicon.ico` located in the root folder of the website). This is where a default favicon should go.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, sorry that my question isn't very clear. Basically, for a couple use cases I want to have a fallback, if one isn't specified in the head, I'd like a way for a default to always be loaded. Wasn't sure if the browser looked for it somewhere if not specified, usually add it how Diodeus listed, so if thats the case thats exactly what I need, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to sniff the server's webroot to see if the favicon is there, if not you can load your own.

Too add one to the page, you need to add this to the `<HEAD>`.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://.../favicon.ico"/>
```